# extjs - groupingstore group item count across page

Tags: extjs

I have a grouping store and group view, and I display the # of Items in each group at the group header.

The problem is, if a group data spans across pages then the (# items) only shows the # of items on the current page, 
e.g. if the group has 10 items and on the first page it shows:
Industry: services (6 Items)
on the second page, it shows:
Industry: services (4 Items)

But I want to show:
Industry: services (10 Items)
on the group header on both pages.

An example of the issue I referred to can be seen in Saki's example:
http://rowactions.extjs.eu/
Industry: Food (1 item) - on the 1st page
Industry: Food (1 item) - on the 2st page
I want to show:
Industry: Food (2 items) - on both page.

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want the grid to display something it has no awareness of. The number of items shown is calculated from the number of items in a group **in the store**.

If you want to display the number of items in a group on the server then server must deliver this information, you need to dig the info from the server response and display it yourself.

Comment: I can get the count from the server. Is there anyway I can override the grouping count so that the look and feel remains same and I dont have to play with that.

Comment: You need to   propagate the value somehow down to the template that renders number of items.